# How to send message in discord api like this on python

Tags: discord, discord.py

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfILv.png)

How to send message in discord api like on photo using python

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a Message you do that via the `await channel.send('Say hello!')` function. If you want to send an Embed, you need to create it first (`myEmbed = discord.Embed(title = "title",description= "description",color=0x000000)`) and then send the Embed with `await channel.send(embed = myEmbed)`. [More in the Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#embed)